# Wrong layout and not secure wordpress via digitalocean

Tags: design

Good Saturday, everyone!

Hope you're chilled out despite the crazy COVID-19!

I recently started to build my website for blogging. However, I followed the instruction but I failed. Here is the website.[enter link description here](http://www.xmoneytree.com/)

The way I tried is first I bought the domain and pointed them each other between two sites.
Then, I saw there is tab called " Marketplace" on DigitalOcean where you can started a do a Dropet for wordpress.

I followed the instruction but I didn't success. I got this layout. I can't google it because I don't what the problem is. You can have a look at this website: wwww.xmoneytree.com

Besides, it shows "Not Secure". How can I make it secure"?

Would any expert mind pointing out some keywords that I can solve this problem?

Thanks,
David

[image: Not a good layout]

Answer (score 1):

All your links at your page point to `moneytree` as the root domain.

For example you have

```
http://moneytree/?page_id=2
```

instead of

```
http://www.xmoneytree.com/?page_id=2
```

None of your assets (JS, CSS) are being loaded for the same reason:

[image: for the same reason]

When you installed WordPress you probably did not specify the correct value for your domain. You can do that either by re-installing WP or by editing `wp-config.php` file and add/edit these:

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://www.xmoneytree.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.xmoneytree.com' );
```

To make your website secure you need a Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) certificate, so that the data transfer between clients and your server is encrypted. Ask your host for SSL service if you don't know how to.